# CUPS printing with Xerox printer

Tags: printing, cups, ppd

New to CUPS administration (and linux printing overall) after inheriting it from someone who left my team.

I'm trying to get it set up with a Xerox AltaLink C8055 printer on Ubuntu. I have installed the .deb package from the Xerox website

```
sudo dpkg -i XeroxOfficev5Pkg-Linuxx86_64-5.20.661.4684.deb
```

with no errors. I thought I would be lucky enough to see the printer model now show up in CUPS, but it doesn't. When running `lpinfo -m | grep "xerox"`, I don't see an entry for the model, which I believe to be the issue.

After a lot of googling, I haven't come up with an answer. Am I missing a step or file when it comes to Linux printing with Cups, or is it just that this printer may not be supported?

EDIT: I was able to find the PPD file and get it to show up, however it doesn't seem to print the test page. I have it set up using socket://ip-address and have the ppd selected. I'm guessing this may be a driver issue.

Answer (score 1):

Xerox doesn't have great documentation, but for future reference should anyone stumble on this one; they packaged all their device specific ppd files in the Generic PPD File package as and EXE.

I was able to use 7z to extract the file and drop it in /usr/share/cups/model, and behold, the driver is available to be selected in CUPS.